# Stop Save File event by using another command button

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

am very new in vb. I have an Excel file which is Auto Saving in intervals. Now I want to stop this Auto Saving Function by Using another Command Button... plz help me ... their is the Code ...

> Private Sub AutoSave_Cmd_click()
>
> dTime = Time + TimeValue("00:00:05") 'Set Time as per requirement
>
> With Application
>
> ```
>    .OnTime dTime, "AutoSaveAs"
>    .EnableEvents = False
>    .DisplayAlerts = False
>    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\<My File Path>\Auto_Save_MACRO.xls"
>    .EnableEvents = True
>    Application.EnableEvents = False
> ```
>
> End With
>
> End Sub

Now my question is what will be the code to stop Auto Save function Through "Stop_Auto_Save_Cmd" command button? Please Help Me ... Thanks in advance ...

> Private Sub Stop_Auto_Save_Cmd_click()
>
> 'What will be the code here?
>
> End Sub

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+cancel+ontime

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet looks a lot like the code found [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=126722) - the difference being that I think the code at my link works, and yours probably doesn't.

When I describe how the "working" code works, you should be able to figure out why yours doesn't:

```
Public dTime As Date 

Sub AutoSaveAs() 
    dTime = Time + TimeValue("00:05:00") 
    With Application 
        .OnTime dTime, "AutoSaveAs" 
        .EnableEvents = False 
        .DisplayAlerts = False 
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "FilePath&NameHere(no .xls)" 
        .EnableEvents = True 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Here you see a `Public` variable `dTime` declared at the module level; it is set to some sensible time (now + five minutes) inside a routine called `AutoSaveAs()`, which then instructs the `Application` (i.e., Excel) to execute another call to `AutoSaveAs` when the timer runs out (in this example, every five minutes). After setting up the "call me again in five minutes" command, it performs the actual SaveAs, with alerts disabled.

To get this to work you need to call `AutoSaveAs` a first time; after that, it will "call itself" because the timer will go off every five minutes (it's like the function keeps hitting its own snooze button, if you like).  This can be done in the code associated with a button that's clicked for "autosave on" functionality (or it could be the AutoOpen event - it depends on what behavior you want):

```
Private Sub AutoSaveOn_Click()
    AutoSaveAs
End Sub
```

And finally, you need something to "turn off" the event loop (instead of "snooze", hit "off" on the alarm clock). Put this in the handler for another ("off") button:

```
Private Sub AutoSaveOff_Click()
    Application.OnTime dTime, "AutoSaveAs", , False 
End Sub
```

The fourth parameter, `False`, says "unschedule this". It turns off the "infinite loop" that was started with the first call to `AutoSaveAs`. It unplugs the alarm clock, if you like.

To be complete, you must add a handler for when the file is closed - because the timer will keep running if you close the workbook but leave Excel open, and that will give a really strange and annoying error message. So you need to do something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
    Application.OnTime dTime, "AutoSaveAs", , False 
End Sub
```

NOTE - I lightly adapted code from the link I gave above, and want to give credit to the original author (Dave Hawley) for the example. All I did was show how to interpret it (and from the similarity to the code you have, I think you have seen the same site, or at least a copy of a copy of the site...)